# How to enable to insert spaces in masked input plugin (JQuery Plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I use masked input plugin, but it forbid enter spaces.
* - Represents an alphanumeric character (A-Z,a-z,0-9), but not allow space-symbol

Comment: Formulate your question properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case if you use http://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask , you can create your own mask:

```
$.extend($.inputmask.defaults.definitions, {
    'A': { 
        validator: "[A-Za-z0-9 ]",
        cardinality: 1
    }
});
$("#field").inputmask("AAA");
```

If you use http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/ , you create you mask like this:

```
$.mask.definitions['A'] = "[A-Za-z0-9 ]";
$("#field").mask("AAA");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change .mask and simply give space after *

```
//following script available in jquery.maskedinput.js
$.mask = {
    //Predefined character definitions
    definitions: {
        '9': "[0-9]",
        'a': "[A-Za-z]",
        '*': "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    },
    dataName: "rawMaskFn",
    placeholder: '_',
};
```

//
if all ,then put *,if only number then put 9,if only alpha then put a

check this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script>
     jQuery(function($)
        { 
        $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';    
        $('#Cell').mask('(*   **)-(99 9)  (a  aa)');        
        }); 


    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Xz8q/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/2Xz8q/2/

Answer (score 0):

just need to input name with blank like this : name = blabla bla bla     and this is my code :

```
  <label for="nom" class="col-md-4 control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span>Nom</label>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nom").inputmask("A", { repeat: 10 }, { "placeholder": "_" });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

in this way you add spaces the key is the \ s that in regular expressions means spaces greetings it is not advisable to put a space between the brackets because it causes a bug

`$('#'+id).mask('ZZ',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[áéíóúñüàèa-zA-Z0-9\s]/, recursive: true}}});`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please write your answer in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)